# undefined this.props.nnavigation.navigate('screen'), how to fix?

Tags: react-navigation

Im trying to use Drawer navigation. I have header.js components which has a hamburger icon to open the left navigation menu

```
//Header.js

 import React from 'react';
 import { Text, View, Image, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
 import { DrawerNavigator  } from 'react-navigation';


 // Make a component
 const Header = (props, {navigate}) => {
 const { textStyle, viewStyle, imgstyle } = styles;

 return (
<View style={viewStyle}>

  <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')}> //here the error is coming
       <Image style={{width:40, height:40}} 
     source={require('./../media/hamburger.png')}
              />
  </TouchableHighlight>

  <Text style={textStyle}>{props.headerText}</Text>
</View>
 );
};
export default Header;
```

Here is App.js

```
    const MyApp = DrawerNavigator({
       Login: {
          screen: Login,
       },
       Signup: {
          screen: Signup,
       },
    });

    export default class App extends React.Component {
       render() {
          return <MyApp />;
       }
    }
```

Here is one of the comoponent Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text, View, StyleSheet
 } from 'react-native';
import Header from './Header';

export default class Login extends Component{
static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'Login',
 };
render(){
    return(
        <View >
            <Header headerText={'Login'}/>
            <Text>Login Screen</Text>
        </View>
         );
       }
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing to fix this. Please check my code.

EDITED:

I tried without "this" to but no luck. I am checking everywhere in the internet but couldn't find the exact solution or I couldn't get a solution to my mind. Can someone who is good with react native respond on this, Please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is - you use `this` keyword in a stateless component: `this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')`.

Try just `props.navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')` since `this` is not pointing to the `Header` component instance in your case.

`this` in a stateless component is "inherited" from the calling scope (since stateless component is an ["arrow" function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) and likely points to `window` or `global`.

Comment: I tried this, but didnt work. Can you suggest any other solutions?